# SQL Update each record with its position in an ordered select

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I'm using Access via OleDb. I have a table with columns ID, GroupID, Time and Place. An application inserts new records into the table, unfortunately the Place isn't calculated correctly.

I want to update each record in a group with its correct place according to its time ascending.

So assume the following data:

```
ID     GroupId  Time   Place
Chuck  1        10:01  2
Alice  1        09:01  3
Bob    1        09:31  1
```

should result in:

```
ID     GroupId  Time   Place
Chuck  1        10:01  3
Alice  1        09:01  1
Bob    1        09:31  2
```

I could come up with a solution using a cursor but that's AFAIK not possible in Access.

Comment: Pardon the bluntness of this question but why?  Place seems to be an artifact of sorting by the time.  Any information you need place for can be derived from an ordinal index into a sorted select.

Comment: Legacy closed source... I know it's a dumb solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a search on performing "ranking in Access" and I got [this support.microsoft result](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208946).

It seems you create a query with a field that has the following expression:

```
Place: (Select Count(*) from table1 Where [Time] < [table1alias].[Time]) + 1
```

I can't test this, so I hope it works.
Using this you may be able to do (where `queryAbove` is the above query):

```
UPDATE table1
SET [Place] = queryAbove.[Place]
FROM queryAbove
WHERE table1.ID = queryAbove.ID
```

It's a long shot but please give it a go.

Comment: unfortunately, I found out access doesn't support subselects in update statements, you can use the DCount function (or any similar) to do it, but it's rather limited for my purposes. I will accept this answer as it pointed me in the right direction to solve this problem, albeit it's not compatible with access.

Comment: Oh, that's odd. The article I linked references Microsoft Access 2000 Standard Edition, so I thought that would work. But thanks for the tick anyway :)  When you get a concrete solution for this, it would be great if you could post it as an answer, as I surely would like to see it in action as I guess other will be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think time is a number or time formatted column, time is unfortunately a text string containing the numbers and dilimetrs of the time format. This is why sorting after the time column is illegal. Removing the dilimiters ":" and "," casting to integer and then sorting numirically could do the job

Comment: huh? The time column is actually *not* my problem. Even if so, your "solution" is still wrong for the problem not at hand.